# GMP Bit shift doesn't work on negative numbers

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, gmp

I found this function at php.net.  It seems to work on positive numbers, but fails on negative ones:

```
function gmp_shiftr($x,$n) { // shift right
  return(gmp_div($x,gmp_pow(2,$n)));
} 

echo -1 >> 8; //returns -1, presumably correctly
echo "<br />";
echo gmp_strval(gmp_shiftr(-1,8)); //returns 0, presumably incorrectly
```

How could I fix up the function to work with negatives?

Two ideas I have:

Maybe I could do something along the lines of

```
if (whatever) { $a >> $b} else{ gmp_shiftr($a, $b) }?
```

Or, maybe I could subtract something from the negative results depending on their value..?

I just want to get the value that >> would give, but also get it for >32bit numbers when I use GMP.

Comment: why the `gmp_shiftr` is removed now?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [GMP documentation for the division routines](http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/manual/html_node/Integer-Division.html#Integer%20Division), there's a function

```
void mpz_tdiv_q_2exp (mpz_t q, mpz_t n, unsigned long int b)
```

that seems like it might be what you want: an arithmetic right shift that treats
`n` as if it were represented in twos-complement, and (I think) shifts it `b` places
to the right.  Unfortunately, that level of the API doesn't seem to be exposed by PHP GMP.

I found a [bit twiddling hack](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#VariableSignExtend) for doing sign extension when the number of bits
in the representation is unknown:

```
unsigned b; // number of bits representing the number in x
int x;      // sign extend this b-bit number to r
int r;      // resulting sign-extended number
int const m = 1U << (b - 1); // mask can be pre-computed if b is fixed

x = x & ((1U << b) - 1);  // (Skip this if bits in x above position b are already zero.)
r = (x ^ m) - m;
```

Since bitwise AND and XOR *are* supported by PHP GMP, you might be able to make
this work...

Answer (score 0):

If you think about this mathematically it makes sense.  gmp_shiftr is doing -1/256, which, when rounding towards zero (the gmp default) is 0.

The ">>" method works like it does because negative numbers are represented in sign-extended twos complement form.

Comment: I thought that too. Then I tested it.

Comment: Ah, I see yes, that is wrong in some cases.  Answer updated to remove incorrect statement.

Comment: So what should I do to get it as if I was doing >>?  Note that I have to use GMP in this loop because it deals with some big #s that go beyond 32bit

Comment: Maybe i could do if (whatever) { $a >> $b} else{ gmp_shiftr($a, $b) }?

Comment: Try adding `$bignum << $b`, then do the `>> $b`, then subtract `$bignum`. bignum is some constant large enough so that the first result is always >=0; it will do what you want (and won't affect >= 0 results).